# Exercise $7.7$ page $82$ Ian Stewart, Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, geometric-construction

Prove that an angle $\theta$ can be trisected by ruler and compasses iff the polynomial $4t^{3}-3t-\cos\theta$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}\left(\cos\theta\right)$

Comment: Hint: ${\rm cos}\  \theta/3$ is a root of that polynomial.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood.

Comment: @chuyenvien94 Then please answer your own question :-)